# CloudFront to EC2 origin returns a 502 error. How can I investigate?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

When I tried to connect cloud front to EC2, I can see the following error.
I set ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com to "origin domain name and path" on Cloud front. What is wrong?

502 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.
CloudFront attempted to establish a connection with the origin, but either the attempt failed or the origin closed the connection. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time.

There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.

If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.

I am looking forward to your reply. :)

Comment: If you put `ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com` into your web browser, does it work? What is the configuration of the inbound Security Group associated with the instance? By the way, you should associate an Elastic IP address with the instance to give it a static IP that won't change in future, and then use that IP address in the CloudFront configuration.

Comment: Does it work without CF?

Comment: It does not work..
I tried to access EC2 directly by domain name and EIP address.
However it denied the access.

For security group, it opens to public.

Answer (score 0):

A 502 error for CloudFront will come down to a number of issues:

- If CloudFront is trying to connect to the origin over HTTPS validate your SSL, is it valid for the origin(s) domain. Use [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) if you want to validate.
- Are these ports open to CloudFront? You'll need to make sure CloudFront can connect publically to your instance. If it's connecting via a private IP address it won't work, and if you are restricting the ports to a specific IP address it will also not work.

You can read more about the reasoning behind the 502 for CloudFront from the AWS documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/http-502-bad-gateway.html).

Any further question let me know.

Comment: Between cloud front and EC2, I am using HTTP. For now I want to use HTTP here.
For security group, EC2 opens to public.

I tried to access EC2 by domain name and EIP address.
But the page denied my access. What is happening?

Comment: Is your instance in a public subnet? For that its route table must have a internet gateway. Are there any other public instances in the same subnet?

Comment: I have two instances in the same subnet.
The acl of subnet is public like this.

#100 ALL Traffic ALL ALL 0.0.0.0/0 ALLOW
*       ALL Traffic ALL ALL 0.0.0.0/0 DENY

Comment: Public subnet means is there an internet gateway attached to a route table that is attached to a subnet

Comment: Can you enable flow logs specifically the ENI of your instance? Might be able to see if any traffic is being rejected? :)

Comment: Okay. Let me get flow log. :)

Comment: I got flow log.
Where should I check?
srcaddr, dstaddr, and action?

Comment: Look for rows that say REJECT

Comment: I checked REJECT. It seems to be okay.
But I could not find my access.

Comment: So if its not REJECT then the traffic is not hitting the 502 error. Maybe double check your origin settings.

Comment: I just realized that I accessed the website by EIP of EC2, but the website was trying to display by HTTPS. Also, the website was not protected by certificate.
How do I make my website display with no certificate?